# Microstrategy : How to increase the number of rows inserted on bulk mode

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, microstrategy

I created a Microstrategy multisources project with parameterized queries activated:
Teradata : lookup tables
Snowflake : Fact tables (primapry database)

When I run a report MSTR create tables on Snowflake and insert data from teradata.

MSTR is doing Multi-row Insert Using Explicitly-specified Values and it's fine for me, but I would like to know how to change the number of values when inserting data (it's note the same number for all tables)

Is there any parameters to change to control the number of rows inserted ?

Thanks

Regards,
Yassine

Comment: BULK loading in snowflake is achieved by COPY statements using Internal/External Stages. This can also be auto-ingested using Snowpipe.

You can find the details:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-bulk.html#bulk-loading-using-copy
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe.html#loading-continuously-using-snowpipe

Comment: @FKayani this has nothing to do with bulk loading data or COPY statements

Comment: This sounds like something that is potentially set in the VLDB properties, are you wanting to set this on a per query basis?

Comment: Hello, I want to set it on the project level.